# Jessie read-only FS problems

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I am trying to make my Raspberry's new Jessie filesystem read-only.. but not having any luck.. Below are the steps that work fine on Wheezy but somehow when I apply this to Jessie the system won't boot anymore.. any ideas?

change /etc/fstab

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults                0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro             0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,ro     0       1
```

Execute the following;

```
rm -rf /var/lib/dhcp/
ln -s /tmp /var/lib/dhcp
rm -rf /var/run /var/spool /var/lock
ln -s /tmp /var/run 
ln -s /tmp /var/spool
ln -s /tmp /var/lock
```

Change boot/cmdline to;

```
> dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1
> root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
> fastboot noswap ro
```

Comment: I believe `cmdline.txt` must be **one line** no matter how long.  You appear to have broken it in three (and in doing so discarded reference to the root partition).  When you want help with this kind of thing, rather than saying it "won't boot anymore" you should describe exactly what does happen, preferably by plugging in a screen and describing that.  It almost certainly *does* boot to an extent (nothing you've done above could prevent that) -- just not the extent you were hoping for.

Comment: And marking the FS RO /etc/fstab won't have any effect in either distribution. The OS won't work unless writable.

Comment: The cmdline.txt is one line.. I guess it was broken up in the copy & paste to here.. and like I said before, these steps work fine on Wheezy.. they just don't work on Jessie. Unfortunatly I don't have the ability to plug in a screen to the device.. all I see is a dim green light flash (while in normal situations its much brighter)..

Answer (score -3):

I've written up step-by-step instructions how to get Jessie running in RO mode:

http://petr.io/2015/11/09/read-only-raspberry-pi-with-jessie/

Hope it helps!

Comment: First, this is a link-only answer which will not last in its present form. Second, the OP have already done something similar to what your instructions describe, but still has a problem. Saying he should have followed your tutorial won't help him now.